# How to select ids that co-exist in one table(Many-To-Many)

Tags: sql

I've stumbled upon a question I've been trying to figure out for the past week and hoping the community could help me out with it. I'll do my best in explaining.

```
 User Table               Channel Table              Member Table
 id | name                    id                   ch.Id | u.Id
----|----                    -----                 -------------
  1 | george                   1                      1  |  1
  2 | john                     2                      1  |  2
  3 | joe                      3                      2  |  1
  4 | jessie                   4                      2  |  3
                                                      3  |  1
                                                      3  |  3
```

So as shown I have 3 tables. The Member's table handles the association between the users and channels table. What I'm trying to do is pull only the user's associated with one channel without identifying the channel within the query.

So far I've got the concept of rendering two given users at the least, but this query as shown below renders both users with every channel they're included in. Again, I'd like to take it a step further and only pull the one channel with the requested users without (if possible) mentioning the channel Id in the query

```
SELECT ch.id as chid, u.id as uid FROM channels AS ch 
  LEFT JOIN members as mem on ch.id = "mem"."channelId" 
  LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = "mem"."userId" WHERE u.id in (1,2);
```

Hopefully I explained this clearly. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select m.*
from members m
where not exists (select 1
                  from members m2
                  where m2.u_id = m.u_id and m2.ch_id <> m.ch_id
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your intentions correctly, the SQL code below should help you.

```
SELECT 
    U.*,
    M.*
FROM USER U
INNER JOIN MEMBER M ON (M.U.ID = U.ID)
WHERE U.ID IN (1,2,3,4)
AND M.CH.ID IN (1,2,3,4);
```

It selects the data without accessing the Channel table. 
Th result will come with repeated lines though, in this case you could GROUP BY the fields that you need, and if you want you can use some functions that work with groups to further process your data (group concat functions).

Also, as already pointed out, you could use EXISTS or NOT EXISTS and subqueries. Bu it can become a performance issue depending on the volume your application should reach.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` clause to identify the users which have only one channel :

```
select u_id
from members m
group by u_id
having min(ch_id) <> max(ch_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

User ID's with only 1 channel ID?

```
select max(mem.channelId) as cid, mem.userId as uid
from members as mem
group by mem.userId
having count(distinct mem.channelId) = 1;
```

And if you worry that the member table contains ID's that got deleted in the other tables?
(Which shouldn't be if foreign keys are used to force the referential integrity)
Then inner join the other tables to it.

```
select max(mem.channelId) as cid, mem.userId as uid
from members as mem
join channels as ch on ch.id = mem.channelId 
join users as u on u.id = mem.userId
group by mem.userId
having count(distinct mem.channelId) = 1;
```

Example snippet:

```
declare @users table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, name varchar(30));
declare @channels table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, name varchar(30));
declare @members table (ChannelId int, UserId int);
insert into @users (name) values ('george'),('john'),('joe'),('jessie');
insert into @channels (name) values ('one'),('two'),('three'),('four');
insert into @members (channelId, userId) values (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,3);

select 
 mem.userId as uid, max(mem.channelId) as cid
 , max(u.name) as uname
 , max(ch.name) as cname
from @members as mem
join @channels as ch on ch.id = mem.channelId
join @users as u on u.id = mem.userId
group by mem.userId
having count(distinct mem.channelId) = 1;
```